# Why is OpenAM is not updating with OpenLDAP information?

Tags: java, ldap, openam

OK so I have checked and all caching is off in Open-AM. Everything works fine if you login to open-AM and change your information, it appears in LDAP and Open-AM correctly. But, if you change any account information like an email address in OpenLDAP using Apache Directory Studio, Open-AM does not appear to update the information it still has the old email in the end user page. So my question is, why would this be occurring?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution for anyone who needs help with this issue. Please go to the following link on forgerock's website.

http://lists.forgerock.org/pipermail/openam/2011-August/002900.html

Comment: Could you quote the solution from that link? It is helpful and appreciated to contain the answer in the post instead of just links.